How does Solr Join perform keyword search?
I want to understand how Solr join works.
Assume, we have these documents
{
"groupid":"test01",
"uniquekey":"test_01",
"content":"test join query content",
"collectionid":["1011"]
}
{
"groupid":"test01",
"uniquekey":"test_02",
"content":"delete after reading",
"collectionid":["1012"]
}
Query1 : q=collectionid:1011&fq={!join from=groupid to=groupid} (content("delete"))&defType=edismax
Query2 : q=collectionid:1011&fq={!join from=groupid to=groupid} (content:("test"))&defType=edismax
Both the query returns document ("uniquekey":"test_01") in the response. I know it returns only left side of the documents in the response.
Does solr join searches keyword on both the sides of join? Help me understand, how are documents actually being joined, how would it look if I had to draw a picture?
I was under impression that keyword search happens only on the right side of the join.
